# XNA, Order highscore list

Tags: c#, list, xna, xna-4.0

Don't really know how to phrase the question, so sorry for the vague title.
Allright. I have created both integers for the current score and slots for 5 scores. Now I want to put the current score in the list of the high scores, at the right location so that it is ordered from low to high.

Example. I just got a score of 7. Now I want to put that into the scoreboard, at first try, I put it at number 1. But after this I get an 8. Now I want to move the 8 to the first location, and the 7 towards the 2nd location. Does anybody have an idea on how to do this?

The only thing I knew before this was how to put the the current score into the high score list/string. I did not know how I would order them.
This is what I had before:

```cs
yourScore = "Your Time: " + Convert.ToString(currentTime * 60);
score1 = "1. " + Convert.ToString(currentTime * 60);
```

Comment: Is this your... homework?

Comment: Well, its for a project for school yeah. But since my school doesn't teach in XNA, I end up with a few questions. Is there a no homework rule here that I don't know of?

Comment: No there is no no homework rule, but there is described in the help which questions you can ask on StackOverflow. See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) As you can read questions should demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved and attempted solutions. Maybe you can add a piece of code and tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: If you are interested there is an interesting topic about homework questions on Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions I looked it up because I got interested if there actually is a no homework rule.

Comment: I edited my main post a bit with the minimal code that I already had. I just didn't know how to order it, hence the question.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use generic lists.

```
List<int> highScores = new List<int>();

highScores.Add(1);
highScores.Add(3);

highScores.OrderBy(i => i); // it is ascending. You could OrderByDescending...
```

(I assumed you were under C#)

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new at this. I still don't understand where I have to specify the current high score, to be submitted into the list. And I'm assuming highScores.Add(1/5) is the list itself, right? 

And if I want to DrawString it onto the screen, what do I need to convert to a string? The entire highScores list or just the specific numbers? In which case, what part of the numbers, the entire highScores.Add(number1); part?

Comment: Lists are similar to arrays. Let's see here: highScores is the list. It's a list of <int> types. The method Add() adds a value at the end of the list. Therefore, you might need to reorder the list. If you want, however, to add a floating point value (e.g. 1.5 or 3/2), you need to declare the list as List<float>. When you want to draw the value as a string, you can do highScores.At(0).ToString(). This means; Take value at position 0, which means the first value in our list, then convert it into a string. Do that in your Drawstring() method.

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to XNA. I would suggest using a List, as Alexandre suggested. His comment excellently describes how List works. You may also want to look at its documentation.

```
List<int> highScores = new List<int>();
```

To add a new high score, you would then do:

```
highScores.Add(4523); // Someone just made a score of 4523.
highScores.Sort();    // This will sort the high scores, putting the lowest high score at position 0.
highScores.Reverse(); // This will reverse the list, putting the highest high score at position 0.
```

When you want to display the high scores table on screen, you could do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < highScores.Count; i++)
{
   int order = i + 1;
   int score = highScores[i];
   screenPosition = new Vector2(0, i * 20);
   spriteBatch.DrawString(yourFont, order + ". " + score, screenPosition, Color.Black);
}
```

That code will put the high score at position (0,0), the second best score at position (0,20) etc.